# Adsense shows an 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN' error

Tags: adsense

Recently I noticed that all my websites give an error in Chrome console (removing adsense the error goes away):

> Refused to display `https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/drt/si?p=******&dpt=1` in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.

Nothing was changed, I don't use iframe, Ads is still visible. But I don't like this error, I read about youtube and maps error, but didn't find any about adsense.

What can I do to fix it?
Page of example: http://www.incinqueterre.com/en/trails-all

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In my case the Google Publisher Toolbar was to blame - turning it off fixed the error.

Comment: Just in case a link is needed for the latest info on the Google Publisher Toolbar. 

https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/9745438?hl=en

Answer (score 1):

I just started getting this error recently as well when using chrome.

From my searching around the interwebs, I found hte following information.  It appears to be a bug in the webkit engine (chrome, safari, et al):

[Invalid 'X-Frame-Options' header from google's Doubleclick response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15236153/invalid-x-frame-options-header-from-googles-doubleclick-response)

https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=110857

Once Chrome (and maybe others) upgrade their version of webkit it will go away.

Comment: That issue got fixed in feb. 2013. But Chrome 38 still shows this error => different issue?

Comment: It is possible that it is related to another issue.  Some of the ad networks need a special directory and file hosted on your web server to allow for the "expand outside the iframe" type ads (they annoying ones).  Doubleclick and Eyeblaster are two that come to mind.

Comment: Interesting.  I will have to see if this is indeed related.  Will try disabling the Publisher toolbar.